# spatie laravel permission doesn't work dynamiclly

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to follow this tutorial:

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/installation-laravel/.

However, when I gave some permissions it can't work. I created the role & permission dynamically. Also, I gave permission dynamically. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean by "it can't work"? Could you please expand on that?

Comment: when I set permission menually it works properly. but when I set it dynamically it doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your Question to reflect what you did, so users do not have to go to the link. Include the information that is currently in comments. (Note also that the link you provided is broken)